# C: Method that handles pointer

Tags: c

I was wondering why the first method does not work but the second does:

//First method

```
int create_node(struct node *create_me, int init){
    create_me = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (create_me == 0){
        perror("Out of momory in ''create_node'' ");
        return -1;
    }
    (*create_me).x = init;
    (*create_me).next = 0;
    return 1;
}

int main( void ){
    struct node *root;
    create_node(root, 0);
    print_all_nodes(root);

}
```

Ok, here the print_all_nodes function tells me, root has not been initialized. Now second method that works fine:

```
struct node* create_node(struct node *create_me, int init){ //<-------
    create_me = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (create_me == 0){
        perror("Out of momory in ''create_node'' ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    (*create_me).x = init;
    (*create_me).next = 0;
    return create_me; //<---------
}


int main( void ){
    struct node *root;
    root = create_node(root, 0); //<---------------
    print_all_nodes(root);

}
```

In my understanding (talking about method 1), when I give the `create_node` function the pointer to the root node, then it actually changes the `x` and the `next` of root.

Like when you do:

```
void change_i(int* p){
    *p = 5;
}
int main( void ){

    int i = 2;
    printf("%d\n", i);
    change_i(&i);
    printf("%d", i);


}
```

It actually changes `i`. 
Get the idea?
Can someone share his/her knowledge with me please !

Comment: Assigning to the parameter has no effect on the outside world. Method 1 works similarly to `void change_i(int p) { p = 5; }`, method 2 is like `int change_i(int p) { p = 5; return p; }`. (One key to understanding pointers is realising that there's nothing special about them.)

Comment: @molbdnilo, could you explain to me what you mean with ,,assigning to the paramter has no effect on the outside world" please?

Comment: C does not support _methods_, but only _functions_ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a pointer to pointer, not just a pointer.

If you want to change a variable in another function, you have to send a pointer to that variable. If the variable is an integer variable, send a pointer to that integer variable. If the variable is a pointer variable, send a pointer to that pointer variable.

You are saying in your question that "when I give the `create_node` function the pointer to the root node, then it actually changes the `x` and the `next` of root." Your wording makes me suspect that there is some confusion here. Yes, you are changing the contents of `x` and `next`, but not of `root`. `root` has no `x` and `next`, since `root` is a pointer that *points* to a struct that contains an `x` and a `next`. Your function does not change the contents of `root`, since what your function gets is only a *copy* of that pointer.

Changes to your code:

```
int create_node(struct node **create_me, int init) {
    *create_me = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (*create_me == 0){
        perror("Out of momory in ''create_node'' ");
        return -1;
    }
    (*create_me)->x = init;
    (*create_me)->next = 0;
    return 1;
}

int main( void ){
    struct node *root;
    create_node(&root, 0);
    print_all_nodes(root);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like `create_node(&root, 0);` and then access it as a `**` in the called method. C doesn't have pass by reference concept. You need to give the address to access it in another function.

Comment: You made it short and easy to look up later once forgotten! Thank you lad!

Answer (score 1):

This is a question of the scope of your variables. In the first example, where you supply a *pointer to a node*, you could change that node and the changes would persist afterwards. However, your `malloc` changes this pointer, which is discarded after the scope (your function) ends.

In the second example you return this pointer and therefore copy it before being discarded.

This would correspond to this in your given example no. 3:

```
void change_i(int* p){
    *p = 5; // you can 'change i'
    p = 5 // but not p (pointer to i), as it is local -> gets discarded after following '}'
}
```

Comment: Did not exactly solve my problem, but is another threat that i will learn about! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> when I give the create_node function the pointer to the root node, then it actually changes the x and the next of root.

You **don't** give the `create_node()` function (in both versions) a pointer to the root node because you don't have the root node, in the first place.

The declaration:

```
struct node *root;
```

creates the variable `root`, of type `struct node *` and lets it uninitialized. `root` is a variable that can store the address in memory of a `struct node` value (a pointer to a `struct node` value). But the code doesn't create any `struct node` value and the value of `root` is just garbage.

Next, both versions of function `create_node()` receive the garbage value of `root` in parameter `create_me` as a consequence of the call:

```
create_node(root, 0);
```

The first thing both implementations of `create_node()` do is to ignore the value they receive in `create_me` parameter (be it valid or not), create a value of type `struct node` and store its address in `create_me`.

The lines:

```
(*create_me).x = init;
(*create_me).next = 0;
```

put some values into the properties of the newly allocated `struct node` object.

The first version of the function then returns 1 and ignores the value stored in `create_me`. Being a function parameter (a local variable of the function), its value is discarded and lost forever. The code just created a memory leak: a block of memory that is allocated but inaccessible because there is no pointer to it. **Don't do this!**

The second version of the function returns the value of `create_me` (i.e. the address of the newly allocated value of type `struct node`). The calling code (`root = create_node(root, 0);`) stores the value returned by the function into the variable `root` (replacing the garbage value used to initialize this variable).

**Great success!** The second version of the `create_node()` function creates a new `struct node` object, initializes its properties and returns the address of the new object to be stored and/or further processed. Don't forget to call [`free(root)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) when the object is not needed any more.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this long answer, i think this serves really well for anyone who googles this question!